# Saving favorites to UserDefaults using struct id

Tags: swiftui, userdefaults

I'm trying to save the users favorite cities in UserDefaults. Found this solution saving the struct ID - builds and runs but does not appear to be saving: On app relaunch, the previously tapped Button is reset.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something…

Here's my data struct and class:

```
struct City: Codable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
}

class Favorites: ObservableObject {
    private var cities: Set<String>
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    var items: [City] = [
        City(name: "London"),
        City(name: "Paris"),
        City(name: "Berlin")
    ]

    init() {
        let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
        if let data = defaults.data(forKey: "Favorites") {
            let cityData = try? decoder.decode(Set<String>.self, from: data)
            self.cities = cityData ?? []
            return
        } else {
            self.cities = []
        }
    }

    func getTaskIds() -> Set<String> {
        return self.cities
    }

    func contains(_ city: City) -> Bool {
        cities.contains(city.id)
    }

    func add(_ city: City) {
        objectWillChange.send()
        cities.contains(city.id)
        save()
    }

    func remove(_ city: City) {
        objectWillChange.send()
        cities.remove(city.id)
        save()
    }

    func save() {
        let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
        if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(tasks) {
            defaults.setValue(encoded, forKey: "Favorites")
        }
    }
}
```

and here's the TestDataView

```
struct TestData: View {

    @StateObject var favorites = Favorites()
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(self.favorites.items, id: \.id) { item in
            VStack {
                Text(item.title)
          
                Button(action: {
                    if self.favorites.contains(item) {
                        self.favorites.remove(item)
                    } else {
                        self.favorites.add(item)
                    }
                }) {
                    HStack {
                        Image(systemName: self.favorites.contains(item) ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                            .foregroundColor(self.favorites.contains(item) ? .red : .white)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were a few issues, which I'll address below. Here's the working code:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @StateObject var favorites = Favorites()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 10) {
            ForEach(Array(self.favorites.cities), id: \.id) { item in
                VStack {
                    Text(item.name)
              
                    Button(action: {
                        if self.favorites.contains(item) {
                            self.favorites.remove(item)
                        } else {
                            self.favorites.add(item)
                        }
                    }) {
                        HStack {
                            Image(systemName: self.favorites.contains(item) ? "heart.fill" : "heart")
                                .foregroundColor(self.favorites.contains(item) ? .red : .black)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }
}

struct City: Codable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID().uuidString
    var name: String
}

class Favorites: ObservableObject {
    @Published var cities: Set<City> = []
    @Published var favorites: Set<String> = []
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard

    var initialItems: [City] = [
        City(name: "London"),
        City(name: "Paris"),
        City(name: "Berlin")
    ]

    init() {
        let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
        
        if let data = defaults.data(forKey: "Cities") {
            cities = (try? decoder.decode(Set<City>.self, from: data)) ?? Set(initialItems)
        } else {
            cities = Set(initialItems)
        }
        self.favorites = Set(defaults.array(forKey: "Favorites") as? [String] ?? [])
    }

    func getTaskIds() -> Set<String> {
        return self.favorites
    }

    func contains(_ city: City) -> Bool {
        favorites.contains(city.id)
    }

    func add(_ city: City) {
        favorites.insert(city.id)
        save()
    }

    func remove(_ city: City) {
        favorites.remove(city.id)
        save()
    }

    func save() {
        let encoder = PropertyListEncoder()
        if let encoded = try? encoder.encode(self.cities) {
            self.defaults.set(encoded, forKey: "Cities")
        }
        self.defaults.set(Array(self.favorites), forKey: "Favorites")
        defaults.synchronize()
    }
}
```

Issues with the original:

1. The biggest issue was that `items` was getting recreated on each new launch and `City` has an `id` that is assigned a `UUID` on creation. This guaranteed that every new launch, each batch of cities would have different `UUID`s, so a saving situation would never work.
2. There were some general typos and references to properties that didn't actually exist.

What I did:

1. Made `cities` and `favorites` both @Published properties so that you don't have to call `objectWillChange.send` by hand
2. On init, load both the cities *and* the favorites. That way, the cities, once initially created, will always have the same UUIDs, since they're getting loaded from a saved state
3. On save, I save both `Set`s -- the favorites *and* the cities
4. In the original `ForEach`, I iterate through all of the `cities` and then only mark the ones that are part of `favorites`

**Important note:** While testing this, I discovered that at least on Xcode 12.3 / iOS 14.3, syncing to `UserDefaults` is *slow*, even when using the now-unrecommended `synchronize` method. I kept wondering why my changes weren't reflected when I killed and then re-opened the app. Eventually figured out that everything works if I give it about 10-15 seconds to sync to `UserDefaults` before killing the app and then opening it again.

Comment: Thanks for your reply and the detailed explanation! Works like a charm. My bad for the typos, as it's part of a much bigger project I broke it down and changed the names to make it more simple. I see where the problem was, everything makes sense now. Thanks a lot!